# Code in your question was edited... but so was not-code in my question

Tags: support, edits, notifications

I got a notification saying `Code in your question LINQ to SQL and null values was edited.`. However, other aspects of the question were also edited (the title, changing a quote to a code block, tagging, editing text etc.).

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12276431/revisions#rev838dd1f8-2e60-4240-af04-d43ce1505ca8

Should the notification just say your question was edited when it isn't specifically/only code that's changed?

Comment: I'm guessing the system thinks changing a quote to a code block is considered "code in your question", because it was *intended* to be code but formatted as a quote instead...

Comment: When I get a notification about a post of mine being edited, the notification doesn't report what was changed. I don't see why, on Stack Overflow, the notification should report exactly what was changed. It is information that is not that important, when I read the notify; when I check the post I wrote, I will see what was exactly changed, if I feel the need to check it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: This is my point, it wasn't just code that was changed. I'd prefer it not being specific when it isn't right. I get that code was changed but the notification gave the impression that was the only change. I would check what the change is anyway, but the notification is still misleading.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: **I'd be happier if it didn't say what was changed.** My issue is that it says code was changed, implying that was the only change.

Comment: And I am saying that __trying to describe what changed in the post doesn't make sense__. What's the problem? To notice I am one of the up-voters.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Sorry, are you saying my description of what changed doesnt make sense, or being told what changed in the notification isn't needed and doesn't make sense? The problem is that the notification is misleading, code wasn't all that was changed, even though that was singled out in the notification.

Comment: I am saying that the message "Code in your question [question title] has been edited." can be replaced by the generic "Your question [question title] has been edited." I said I didn't see that message outside Stack Overflow just to mean that, if Stack Overflow is the only site using that message, then it is a reason more to change it to the more generic message. On sites like English language & Usage, it would not probably make sense to check if the change was about code, as those sites are not supposed to use code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Ahh ok, thanks for the clarification.